# (python: twilio package) error: could not build wheels for multidict

Tags: python, package, twilio

I tried to install Twilio package for my project but its showing build not successful for multidict(wheels) and showing a bunch of errors.

1. subprocess excited with error.
2. Microsoft visual C++ 14.0 or more required.

so I updated pip, setuptools wheel  Also, I tried to download the Multidict, Twilio package explicitly to my package configuration but ended up with the same error. so if anyone knows the solution please share it.

Comment: Please include the complete error message as texts in your question

Comment: Sooo.... did you install Visual C++? If so, please [edit] your question and add more details like the exact error message, whether the C++ compiler is on the path, and anything else to reproduce the issue. See [ask].